# Solution differential equation via Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Please help me finish this problem.

$xy''+(3x-1)y'-(4x+9)y=0$ where $y(0)=0$

$L[xy'']+L[(3x-1)y']-L[(4x+9)y]=L[0]$

$L[xy'']=\frac{d}{dp}(p^2Y)$

$L[(3x-1)y']=-3\frac{d}{dp}(pY)$

$L[(4x+9)y]=-4\frac{dY}{dp}$

$-\frac{d}{dp}(p^2Y)-3\frac{d}{dp}(pY)+4\frac{dY}{dp}=0$

$-\frac{d}{dp}(p^2Y)-(3pY)\frac{d}{dp}+4\frac{dY}{dp}=0$

I don't know what to do from here and would really appreciate some help finishing the problem.

Comment: It's just a separable equation. Onward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\int \frac{dY}{3Y} = \int\frac{dp}{4-p^2}.$$

The first integral is trivial, you should be okay from here. The second can be equivalently expressed as

$$ \int\frac{dp}{4-p^2}  \equiv \frac{1}{4}\int \left( \frac{1}{(2+p)} - \frac{1}{(2-p)} \right) dp.$$

You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: When I integrate it I get $1/3ln(Y)=1/4(ln(p/2+1)-ln(p/2-1))$ When I take the ln of both sides and isolate Y I get $Y=(p/2+1)^\frac{3}{4}+(p/2-1)^\frac{3}{4}+C$ but I don't think this is the correct answer.

Comment: @thisisme why don't you think that is the correct answer?

Comment: Because my textbook states that the solution is $Y=cx^2e^x$

Comment: Don't forget you need to also perform an inverse Laplace transform to get the desired result. Although, I have a feeling you have made a mistake somewhere early on.

Comment: I tried looking for my mistake but was unable to find it. Could you please help me out with it?

Comment: I don't have time at the minute but a helpful hint. What is the Laplace transform of $x^2 e^x$? This will give you an idea of what you are looking for and potentially identify your mistake.

Comment: I will think about it, thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the Laplace transform of the differential equation, you should get
$$ \left( -{p}^{2}-3\,p+4 \right) {\frac {\rm dY}{{\rm d}p}} -3\,pY  -12\,Y 
 = 0 $$
and factoring out $p+4$,
$$ (p-1) \dfrac{dY}{dp} + 3 Y = 0$$
That's a separable first-order equation, which you should be able to solve...

Comment: Isn't $+ 3 Y$ in the last equation?

Comment: Yes, thanks (fixed).

Comment: By the way, for future reference, this is the correct answer (not the accepted one).